# Validation error when uploading localized custom user attribute in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to localize a custom user attribute named Hobby in Azure AD B2C.

This is the definition of the attribute in the user flow:

[image: Hobby custom user attribute in user flow]

According to the docs here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/language-customization?pivots=b2c-user-flow#change-extension-attributes, the localization should be done by adding the following element to the resource file:

```
{
  "LocalizedStrings": [
    {
      "ElementType": "ClaimType",
      "ElementId": "extension_<ExtensionAttribute>",
      "StringId": "DisplayName",
      "Override": true,
      "Value": "<ExtensionAttributeValue>"
    }
    [...]
  ]
}
```

So I added the following to the top of the file (as the first item of the `LocalizedStrings` array):

```
   {
      "ElementType": "ClaimType",
      "ElementId": "extension_Hobby",
      "StringId": "DisplayName",
      "Override": true,
      "Value": "Passatempo"
    },
```

However, when uploading the file back to B2C, I keep getting the following error:

> 1 Validation errors found in upload overrides for
> api.signinandsignupwithpassword1.1. Please ensure that your uploaded
> resource matches the template: The localized string with ElementType:
> ClaimType, ElementId: extension_Hobby and StringId: DisplayName is not
> a valid override.

No matter how I try to modify the snippet (lowercase / uppercase, remove the "extension" part, etc.) - I can't make it work.

What am I missing? Why doesn't it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I created custom user attribute named **Hobby** via ***[Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)*** using below query:

```http
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/identity/userFlowAttributes
Content-type: application/json

{
  "displayName": "Hobby",
  "description": "Your hobby",
  "dataType": "string",
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

I added this custom user attribute named **Hobby** like below:

[image]

When I ran the user flow and selected **Sign up now**, I got the screen asking for **`Hobby`** like below:

[image]

To **localize** this custom user attribute, I added the following as the first item of the `LocalizedStrings` array like below:

```json
   {
      "ElementType": "ClaimType",
      "ElementId": "extension_Hobby",
      "StringId": "DisplayName",
      "Override": true,
      "Value": "Passatempo"
    },
```

**Json file:**

[image]

When I tried to upload this file, I got the **same error as you** like below:

[image]

To **resolve** the error, you need to download ***valid resource file*** i.e., `Local account sign up page` like below:

[image]

Find **`hobby`** in that downloaded file and modify it like below:

```json
   {
      "ElementType": "ClaimType",
      "ElementId": "extension_Hobby",
      "StringId": "DisplayName",
      "Override": true,
      "Value": "Passatempo"
    },
```

**Json file:**

[image]

When I uploaded that file to ***Local account sign up page*** in User flow, it overrode successfully like below:

[image]

Now, I ran the user flow by enabling **Localization** as below:

[image]

When I selected **Sign up now**, `Hobby` changed to **overridden** value successfully like below:

[image]

Please **note** that, you can only override values which appears on that specific page. You will get **`Hobby`** on Sign up page. So, you need to modify ***Local account sign up page***.

Comment: Yes, that was it! I used the wrong page resource file. Thanks!